# Cannot read property 'post' of undefined?

Tags: angular, jwt, auth0, angular2-jwt

TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

This is happening when we generate an app in production. In development mode, everything works perfectly. Only in production mode http.post is not defined.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {JwtCredentials} from '../login/jwt-credentials';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MEAT_API } from '../app.api';
import { AuthHttp, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class JwtCliente {

  private _token = null;
  private _payload = null;

  constructor(public http: AuthHttp, public jwtHelper: JwtHelper) { }



  assessToken(jwtCredentials: JwtCredentials): Observable<any> {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
      return this.http.post(`${MEAT_API}api-token-verify/`, jwtCredentials,
          new ResponseOptions({headers: headers}))
          .map((response) => {
            let token = response.json().token;
            this._token = token;
            localStorage.setItem('token', this._token);
            return token;
          });
    }


}
```

> vendor.2a1591e60e00b8e65016.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'post' of undefined
>       at l.assessToken (main.951fcf271be890a69879.bundle.js:1)
>       at l.Ct5P.l.login (main.951fcf271be890a69879.bundle.js:1)
>       at l.K181.l.login (main.951fcf271be890a69879.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.handleEvent (main.951fcf271be890a69879.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object._ [as handleEvent] (vendor.2a1591e60e00b8e65016.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.handleEvent (vendor.2a1591e60e00b8e65016.bundle.js:1)
>       at ie (vendor.2a1591e60e00b8e65016.bundle.js:1)
>       at vendor.2a1591e60e00b8e65016.bundle.js:1
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (vendor.2a1591e60e00b8e65016.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.invokeTask (polyfills.939bb971810907071b8d.bundle.js:1)

Comment: paste your `AuthHttp`

Comment: Hi. 
It's a library - https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Comment: @user2716095, please add the **exact** code that calls assessToken().

Comment: Hi.  login(jwtCredentials: JwtCredentials): Observable<Object> {
      return this.jwtCliente.assessToken(jwtCredentials)
          .map((response) => response);
  }

Comment: did you configure that exactly like in https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt `Basic Configuration` section?

Comment: I did a little different. {
        provide: AuthHttp,
          deps: [Http, RequestOptions],
          useFactory(http) {
            let authConfig = new AuthConfig({
                headerPrefix: 'JWT',
                noJwtError: true,
                noClientCheck: true,
                tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('token'))
            });
            return new AuthHttp(authConfig, http);
          }
      }

Comment: Kuncevic, it worked. I used the basic configuration format. Thank you very much, grateful for your attention.